# Can't install winget-cli on Windows 10 LTSC

Tags: windows, powershell, dependencies, appx, winget

I'm trying to install the winget-cli on my Win10 LTSC but it shows me a dependency error [as you see here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Tqr6.png)

"Provide the framework"Microsoft.VCLibs.140.00.UWPDesktop" published by "CN=Microsoft Corporation, O=Microsoft Corporation, L=Redmond, S=Washington, C=US", with neutral or x64 processor architecture and minimumversion 14.0.25426.0, along with this package to install."

and already tried to install the "C++ Runtime v14 framework package for Desktop Bridge" and the "%programfiles(x86)%\Microsoft SDKs\Windows Kits\10\ExtensionSDKs\Microsoft.VCLibs.Desktop\14.0\Appx" appx's were included with the Add-AppxPackage but doesn't seem to work :/

How can I install it?

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issues installing and running winget. **I needed the latest version of winget.** Got it working as follows:

1. Go to the application path `%userprofile%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps` [image]
2. If winget.exe exists, skip this step, otherwise make sure you meet conditions or try to download & install the latest **`.appxbundle`** from https://github.com/microsoft/winget-cli/releases [image]
3. Then go to your Environment Variables (if you can't find it, type it on Windows Search) [image]
4. Click Edit, Environment Variables, Path, New [image]
5. Then enter `%userprofile%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\`
6. Click Ok for all dialogs
7. Open a new command line window (run-as Administrator is best)
8. Should now work

Answer (score 0):

To install the package:

1. Go to [this microsoft link](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/troubleshoot/developer/visualstudio/cpp/libraries/c-runtime-packages-desktop-bridge#how-to-install-and-update-desktop-framework-packages) and download your specific arch version for the .appx file.
2. Intall the package using the powershell cmdlet `Add-AppxPackage`
3. Try installing winget-cli again.

I also have installed this winget-cli package in win LTSC, but I got other issue with a framework called 'Microsoft.UI.Xaml' in the version 2.7, try following the steps I described in [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75991641/17400037) to another question for installing this package