# How Install Specific Version Of Microsoft.UI.Xaml

Tags: powershell, xaml, nuget, appxmanifest

I'm trying to install WindowsSubsytemAndroid and PowerShell tell me that I Need The Following:

"Microsoft.UI.Xaml.2.6" with minimum version 2.62108.18004.0.

I managed to install (Get-AppxPackage Show This Two):

Microsoft.UI.Xaml.2.6 2.62106.23002.0

Microsoft.UI.Xaml.2.7 7.2109.13004.0

But This Doesn't Solve The Problem. Any Idea ?

Comment: There is a [general instruction](http://woshub.com/how-to-download-appx-installation-file-for-any-windows-store-app/) on how to download and install all the required components for any app from the Microsoft Store

Answer (score 4, accepted):

click this link https://store.rg-adguard.net/
URL: https://www.microsoft.com/store/productId/9P3395VX91NR
Channel: Slow
click the tick button, below you will get a set of files. select the files you want and install it via powershell

Comment: https://allthings.how/how-to-download-windows-subsystem-for-android-without-microsoft-store-msixbundle/ gives a step by step instruction. I was stuck with the Microsoft.UI.XAML.2.7 error. After installing from above link by Phil WSA worked fine.

Answer (score 2):

The right way to install this dependency and related dependencies developed by Microsoft is to download it from their respective repositories at the [Microsoft Github Organization](https://github.com/microsoft).

In this case the realeses for the "Microsoft.UI.Xaml" framework are in the folowing link [Microsoft-ui-xaml releases page](https://github.com/microsoft/microsoft-ui-xaml/releases), simply search for the required version and then you can download source code and built it.

Or you can use the referenced link for [Microsoft UI xaml nuget package page](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.UI.Xaml). Then follow the steps:

1. Search for the needed version in the versions tab.
2. Download the raw nupkg file for the package.
3. Locate the downloaded file and change its extension to .zip.
4. Extract the ***Microsoft.UI.Xaml.X.X.appx*** file inside the **microsoft.ui.xaml.X.X.X.zip\tools\AppX\x64\Release** directory.
5. Open powershell, go to the appx file location and execute:

   Add-AppxPackage -Path .\Microsoft.UI.Xaml.X.X.appx

This should solve your problem, remember to replace the X.X for your specific required version for the package. Also extract the appx for your specific system architecture.

Regards to jedieaston for his [contribution](https://github.com/microsoft/winget-cli/issues/1861#issuecomment-1021240355).

Answer (score 0):

Once you navigate to the folder where the downloaded file exists (in powershell)
run this command to install.

Add-AppxPackage Microsoft.UI.Xaml.2.7_7.2109.13004.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe.Appx